# using find in python

Tags: python, indexing, find, raw-input

New to python, my assignment asks to ask user for input and then find and print the first letter of each word in the sentence

so far all I have is

```
phrase = raw_input("Please enter a sentence of 3 or 4 words: ")
```

^ That is all I have. So say the user enters the phrase "hey how are you" I am supposed to find and print the first letter of every word so it would print "hhay"

I know how to index if it is a string that the programmer types but not when a user inputs the data.

Comment: Ok. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: For hint you can use `string's split` built-in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does everything that [Ming](https://stackoverflow.com/users/904117/ming) said in a single line.
You can very well understand this code if you read his explanation.

```
phrase = raw_input("Please enter a sentence of 3 or 4 words: ")    
output = ''.join([x[0] for x in phrase.split()])    
print output
```

Update related to comment (Considers only first 3 words):

```
output = ''.join([x[0] for x in phrase.split()])[:3]
```

Ignoring the last word (Total number of words doesn't matter)

```
output = ''.join([x[0] for x in phrase.split()])[:-1]
```

Comment: thanks Alfie this helped! For the next one I have to join the first letters of only the first 3 words and ignore the 4th word. How do I do that?

Comment: Is it certain that the sentence would have only 3 or maximum 4 words?

Comment: Yes it is certain that the sentence would have only 3 or 4 words

Answer (score 0):

Here are a rough outline of the steps you can take. Since this is an assignment, I will leave actually assembling them into a working program up to you.

1. `raw_input` will produce a string.
2. If you have two strings, one in `foo` and one in `bar`, then you can call [`string.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) as `foo.split(bar)`, and the result of that will be a list of strings resulting from splitting the contents of `foo` by the separator `bar`. For example, `'a b c'.split(' ') == ['a', 'b', 'c']`.
3. You can slice a string with brackets to retrieve particular characters from it, counting from zero in the leftmost position. For example, `'abcd'[0] == 'a'`.
4. If you have a string `foo` and a list of strings `bar`, then you can call [`string.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) as `foo.join(bar)` to produce a single string of the elements of `foo` glued together with `bar`. For example, `'x'.join(['a', 'b', 'c']) == 'axbxc'`.
5. You can `print` the constructed output.

This is of course only one of many approaches you could take.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your question "For the next one I have to join the first letters of only the first 3 words and ignore the 4th word. How do I do that?"

```
output = ''.join([x[0] for x in phrase.split()[0:3]])
```

If instead it is first character of all word but the last then use :

```
output = ''.join([x[0] for x in phrase.split()[0:len(phrase.split()) - 1]])
```